# A simple extends will not work, how to do it in scala

Tags: scala

I tried to play with scala and somethings wrong here. Maybe because its too late or maybe because eclipse wont work fine, but I have here an error:

```
    class A(
      val name: String,
      val age: Integer,
      val pro: Boolean
    )

    class B(val size: Integer) extends A(name, age, pro) //error
```

- not found: value age  B.scala /Test/src   line 1  Scala Problem
- not found: value name B.scala /Test/src   line 1  Scala Problem
- not found: value pro  B.scala /Test/src   line 1  Scala Problem

Class A is in the same package. I tought thats the way how extends work... somebody an idea?

Comment: Consider what value would be provided for name, age and pro if that compiled and then you did val b = new B(4).  Incidentally, Int will normally be a better choice than Integer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you define `class B(val size: Integer) extends A(name, age, pro)` you also define a constructor that will call the constructor from `A` with the `name`, `age`, `pro` parameters. The compiler complains that that variables are not defined.

So may be something like this it what you need:

```
class B(val size: Integer
  name: String,
  age: Integer,
  pro: Boolean) extends A(name, age, pro)
```

On an unrelated note, the type for integer in Scala is typically called `Int`. `Integer` refers to `java.lang.Integer`. Usually `Int` works just fine unless you are running into Java interoperability issues.